# MySQL will connect on the command line with u/p but not mysqldump

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1045

It's driving me mad!

I can connect to my server's MySQL via Terminal using:
    mysql -u admin -p and then password fine.

Trying the same with:
    mysqldump --user admin --password=mypassword test123 > /backups/test.sql
just gets me mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user

Any words of wisdom for me, do I need to grant more priviledges to admin?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Your mysqldump commandline is wrong. use

`--user=admin`

or

`-u admin`

Answer (score 0):

As i see, you do the wrong command, because is: mysqldump --user=admin --password=mypassword test123 > /backups/test.sql i suggest to add --opt and -h serverip just to be sure.